# Flutter: Get list of contacts only signed up in my flutter app using Firebase Auth (like WhatsApp)

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I build an application similar to the chat applications, the user signup via the phone number using the Firebase Auth.

How I can create a list of the contacts stored by the user in their phone that is signed up in the application, such as those in the WhatsApp application.

[image: example from WhatsApp]

Comment: Could be a nice feature added to https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts/issues/160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to fetch the phone contacts is already answered here [Fetching contacts in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921348/fetching-contacts-in-flutter)

Now you need think of your own way how you would create a list of those contacts which are also using the app. One option would be to make a query to your database for each phone number of the devices contact list and if its in the database you know this contact is also signed up, so you can add it to your list.